# Metal detector circuit description

Tags: circuit-analysis, detector, documentation, metal, information

I found a circuit for this metal detector and would like to make PCB. I can not find anything about this circuit. Maybe someone would know what this circuit is. What are the best component housings to choose for a metal detector?

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ustsq.png]

Comment: You should read what the author wrote about it. It's difficult to reverse engineer out details like *housings* from a schematic. Normally, I'd guess that \$L_1\$ and \$C_4\$  are in your metal detector 'coil and housing' that you use to sweep the area. However, I'm not at all feeling good about either the left side driver circuit or the right side receiver portion, for which I cannot see any way you can hear or see a result. I think you really need to see what the author is writing about this.

Answer (score 1):

The left opamp creates a Wein Bridge oscillator at about 78 kHz. L1 is probably the detector coil, whoever designed this should be able to tell you how many turns of wire and what diameter the coil should be.

I am assuming that when metal is put near the coil the resonant frequency will change to something near the oscillator frequency. When the sine input to L1/C4 hits the resonance frequency, the signal will be amplified. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LC_circuit

The right opamp amplifies the signal further and the diode and cap on the right are a peak detector. You will need to connect something with high impedance to the right side, maybe a voltmeter.

The Wein Bridge oscillator is difficult to simulate (from prior experience), but the middle part is easy. L1 needs to be about 14 uH for a resonance of 78 kHz.

This is a really poor, incomplete metal detector. The sensitivity will be terrible. You should find a better circuit.

Just to get the Wein Bridge oscillator to work is a challenge. It needs a non-linear element to set the gain, read the Wikipedia article.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wien_bridge_oscillator

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4AlQw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>